# Django UserChangeForm custom validation

Tags: django, django-forms

**ValueError: The Custom_User could not be changed because the data didn't validate.**

I am trying to make a UserChangeForm to allow customers to edit their address, contact or password. However, for the field "*postal code*" I have set a restriction where there are only certain postal addresses I want to service.

```
#forms.py
#Extract list of postal codes which are valid and put into a list
valid_postal_code = []
postal_code_model = PostalCode.objects.all()
for code in postal_code_model:
    valid_postal_code.append(code.postal_code)

#form
class EditAccountForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Custom_User
        fields = (
            'address',
            'postal_code',
            'unit_number',
            'email',
            'contact_number',
            'password'          
            )
    def clean_postal_code(self):
        post_code = self.cleaned_data.get('postal_code')
        if post_code not in valid_postal_code:
            print('hello')
            raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry we do not serve this postal code right now D:')
        return post_code
```

If the user inputs a postal code that is not in the **valid_postal_code list**, I would like that the form be able to raise an Error message on the form. 
However, I get the above error(which is to be expected), straight away without the raising for error.

```
#views.py
def edit_info_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditAccountForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            print('form changed')
            return redirect('home:edit_info_page')
    else:
        form = EditAccountForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'sign/edit_info.html', {'form':form})


#models
class Custom_User(AbstractUser):
    postal_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    unit_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    order_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total_spending = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Above are my models and views for reference. IMO, I think I am definitely missing something here but Im just not too sure how to break into the UserChangeForm. I'm still a relative newbie (haven't sent anything into production yet). Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view change:

```
if form.is_valid:
```

to

```
if form.is_valid():
```

The validation is not getting executed, which consequently does not validate your post data, which in turn does not allow you to save the user.

Suggestion:

Change
`if post_code not in valid_postal_code:`

to

`if post_code and post_code not in valid_postal_code:`

to ensure to raise the error only if user has entered something.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, that solved it... Cant believe it was such a silly mistake! thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class EditAccountForm(UserChangeForm):
class Meta:
    model = Custom_User
    fields = (
        'address',
        'postal_code',
        'unit_number',
        'email',
        'contact_number',
        'password'          
        )
def clean_postal_code(self):
valid_postal_code = PostalCode.objects.all().values_list('postal_code', flat=True)
    post_code = self.cleaned_data.get('postal_code')
    if post_code not in valid_postal_code:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry we do not serve this postal code right now D:')
    return post_code
```

Better way to write AJAX call for postal_code field and call ajax function from postal_code focus out/blur event, 
Or Make the postal code field auto complete or selection field

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back! I also have several other forms that require the "valid_postal_code" list and would want it to load 'globally' first in the forms.py file! But thanks, will look into your method! But my main frustration is getting the error to be raised :///

Comment: check and confirm valid_postal_code list is available there or not. print the valid_postal_code list before the if statement